# Install Syncfusion Dashboard to local machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syncfusion

How i can install syncfusion dashboard for react to local machine ? 
I have test local project, i want send data via API to syncfusion dashboard, for manage data.

In official documentation information only about how i can install and configure to azure and from windows platform, but i'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Synfusion dashboards are compatible only with Windows platform. And also the Syncfusion Dashboard Platform SDK currently doesn't have support for react. 
We have logged a feature request for the same. Please watch the Syncfusion space for further updates.